# measuring the phonegap application size

Tags: iphone, cordova, compilation

Hi I'm brand new to Phonegap and I'm conscious that there are size limitations when building mobile apps.  Where can I found out the size of my app as I develop.  I'm using XCode and the iphone simulator to test the app as I develop but am not sure where I can find the compiled app size.

Comment: When you archive your app in Xcode it will give you an estimated size.

Comment: Thanks I had seen that solution but hadn't registered yet with the Apple Developer program so it wasn't available to me.  Have registered now and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2 GB** is the maximum size your iOS app can be. iOS App binary files (either developed using native or third party) can be as large as 2 GB, but the executable file (app_name.app/app_name) cannot exceed 60MB.

Read Page 58 in this [developer.apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/iTunesConnect_Guide.pdf)

IPA archive (IPhone App) is the file which is downloaded by users from the App Store.So create an IPA of you app and check the size.